# Properly formatting currency values based only on ISO4217 currency code?

Tags: ios, currency, iso, nsnumberformatter

I am using a web API that returns values like this:

```
{
    "CNY": 42.0,
    "DKK": 31337.00,
    "EUR": 6789.01,
    "GBP": 6502.00,
    "USD": 12345.67,
...
}
```

I would like to format these values as proper currency values (e.g. for USD, "$12,345.67," for EUR, "6789.01€", for GBP, "£6502.00", for DKK, "31337.00 DKK", etc.)  In other words, using the proper symbol ($, £, etc.), but also for some currencies, the symbol comes before the amount whereas for others, it comes after the amount, etc.

The catch is the API I am using only returns ISO4217 country codes ("USD," "EUR," "CNY," etc.) instead of locales.  I know `NSNumberFormatter` has an `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` which looks like it does the proper formatting, but apparently the only way you can tell it what type of currency you're dealing with is by handing an `NSLocale` to its `setLocale`.

Is there any way to convert from ISO4217 currency codes to locales, other than hardcoding a ISO4217->locale conversion table in my code (which, granted, might work ok since ISO4217->locale mappings probably don't change very often??)  Still, I would prefer a way of doing this programmatically if possible.

Comment: See the `setCurrencyCode:` method of `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: Ugh.  I need to have my eyes examined.  I have no idea how I managed to miss that in the `NSNumberFormatter` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot map currency codes to locales - with the Euro this just *must* fail because there are probably 50 locales using Euro.

What you need to do is display the currency according to the locale of the user. Users in Germany, Britain, USA, can all display Euros, for example, and do it in different ways. Each locale can display all currencies.